# pass multiple class function pointer as function parameter in c++

Tags: c++, function-pointers

> I am newly learning function pointer and able to pass function pointer between classes.
> Now i am looking to receive function pointer parameter of all the other classes.
>
> **fncptr2.h**

```
 #ifndef FNCPTR2
 #define FNCPTR2

 class fncptr1;

 class fncptr2
 {
    public:
      int implfncptr(int (fncptr1::*add)(int,int));
 }; 

 #endif
```

> **fncptr2.cpp**

```
#include "fncptr2.h"
#include "fncptr1.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

fncptr1 ff;

int fncptr2::implfncptr(int (fncptr1::*add)(int, int))
{
   return (ff.*add)(1,2);
}
```

> **fncptr1.h**

```
#ifndef FNCPTR1
#define FNCPTR1

class fncptr1
{
  public:
    int addition(int a,int b);
    void testfncptr();

};

#endif
```

> **fncptr1.cpp**

```
   #include "fncptr1.h"
#include "fncptr2.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int fncptr1::addition(int a,int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

void fncptr1::testfncptr()
{
   fncptr2 f;
   f.implfncptr(&fncptr1::addition);
 }
```

> **main.cpp**

```
fncptr1 f;
f.testfncptr();
```

> The above sample code works fine. Now looking to receive all the function pointers in

```
int implfncptr(int (fncptr1::*add)(int,int));
```

> Instead of receive fncptr1 function pointer , looking to receive the function pointers from all the other classes
>
> Example

```
int implfncptr(int (AllClassInstance::*add)(int,int));
```

Comment: Your question doesn't quite make sense. Are you suggesting you want to have a more generic answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, your question doesn't quite make sense, but it sounds like what you want is a more generic solution. First, I don't use function pointers the way you've got them. This is very C-style, and there are better ways. My definition of "better" means "fits more solutions". There might be a very slight performance hit for the way I prefer.

```
 #include <functional>

 class Foo {
 public:
     typedef std::function<bool(std::string &)> MyFunct;

     void someMethod(MyFunct funct) {
         std::string str = "Foo";
         if (funct(str)) {
             ...
         }
     }
 };

 // Then somewhere else, you can do this:


 bool f(const std::string &str) {
     return str.length() > 10;
 }

 Foo foo;
 foo.someMethod(f);
```

But the reason I like this is that you can also use lambdas:

```
 Foo foo;
 foo.someMethod([](const std::string &str) { return str.length() > 10; });
```

Or you can pre-define the lambda like this:

```
 Foo::MyFunct f = [](const std::string &str) { return str.length() > 10; };

 foo.someMethod(f);
```

I don't know if this actually helps you advance what you're trying to do, as your question isn't quite clear as I write this answer. But this might help by providing a few other ways to accomplish what you want.

I'm sure there's an argument for C-style function pointers, but the functional interface offers better features, in my view.